# Add values from feed into the users database table

Tags: users, importing-exporting

I am new in Drupal. I am currently building a stand alone website (non Drupal website) but want people to register through the custom form and all the users data to go into the Drupal's database.

So the admin can manage the users through Drupal admin.

I am initially thinking to use a custom form so users can insert the information and then store all the values in JSON file and then install a module in Drupal to get the JSON's information and then store them into the Drupal user's table.

I will really appreciate your support and suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use HEADLESS Drupal. This means using Drupal as a backend, but with the front end being entirely separate to that. You do this by creating a REST server in Drupal, through which you can perform various actions, such as registering and logging in users.

If you are using (or will use) Drupal 7, a server can be created through the [Services module](http://dgo.to/services). If you are doing it in Drupal 8, it is part of core.

You should set up your system to use OAuth2 authentication. This requires the [OAuth2 server module](http://dgo.to/oauth2_server), though I'm not sure what is necessary for Drupal 8.

With the REST server set up, you can create a form on whatever site you want, and you will then register the user through the REST server. Users can be authenticated (logged in) the same way.

Comment: This is definitely a good option, there is a default user resource with the service module and it has a POST action for creating users. A Google search should get you a walkthrough.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am kind of newbie in the Drupal area. Is there any walk through type of thing i can find to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) would work for this.

It's a well-known module so have a look at some Youtube videos to get an idea of how to use it.

Feeds extensible parsers simply adds JSON capabilities.